# operating system not found after installion from cd

Tags: 14.04, live-cd, reboot

I have succefully installed ubuntu 14.04 on sony vaio. After i click reboot now, it reboots and then says no operating system found! i tried to insert again the cd it enters and says try ubuntu or install . i click install the check on having more than 6.3 mb is not appered .

hope you have the answer regards!

Answer (score 0):

are you typing from windows? if you are follow the last step (Note:) from http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

Comment: sorry i didnt understand

Comment: well i did some partitions for like / for start up and yea

Comment: Note: If after installing Ubuntu, you boot directly in Windows, check in UEFI settings for changing the boot order. If you see no option to set the boot to Ubuntu, you need to fix it from within Windows. When you are in Windows desktop, hover the mouse in left corner, right click and select administrator’s command prompt. Then run the following command:

bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
This should make the Grub default and hence you can access both Ubuntu and Windows from it.

Comment: remove the cd. it's no longer needed

Comment: no i didnt choose the dual boot nor i dont have an option to boot to windows i tried boot repair from try ubuntu thats what i got http://paste.ubuntu.com/10969696/

Comment: should i install updates would it help in something?

Comment: Are you sure the installation was sucessfull the first time? There is no Harddrive detected in the boot info pastebin